Rails delete record from joins table: delete_all fails when using additional joins
Happens both at Rails V 5.2.8.1 and Rails 7.1.3.2
My models:
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class CommentsUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user
end

I can do regular select with join:

users_ids = [197]
book_id   = 659

CommentsUser.joins(:comment).where(comments: {book_id: book_id}, user_id: users_ids)
# CommentsUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "comments_users".* FROM "comments_users" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."id" = "comments_users"."comment_id" WHERE "comments"."book_id" = $1 AND "comments_users"."user_id" = $2  [["book_id", 659], ["user_id", 197]]

But it fails If I use delete_all (notice the "comments_users"."":
CommentsUser.joins(:comment).where(comments: {book_id: book_id}, user_id: users_ids).delete_all
# CommentsUser Destroy (0.8ms)  DELETE FROM "comments_users" WHERE ("comments_users"."") IN (SELECT "comments_users"."" FROM "comments_users" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."id" = "comments_users"."comment_id" WHERE "comments"."book_id" = $1 AND "comments_users"."user_id" = $2)  [["book_id", 659], ["user_id", 197]]

# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
# LINE 1: ...comments_users" WHERE ("comments_users"."") IN (SE...

I want to use the same logic used in the first statement to use it for deleting the records- I can find the records, but I can't delete them- any ideas?
-------edit-----
CommentsUser has no primary key
CommentsUser.primary_key
# => nil

I can use the where to find records, without adding primary key, is there no way to delete those records as well?

It seems like your comments_users table missing a primary key. What does CommentsUser.primary_key return? What does the migration for this table look like? What happens if you call CommentsUser.find(1)? Also the rails version would be a useful addition to the post.

In a HABTM (Has and Belongs to Many) relationship, Rails does not generate a primary key for the join table by default. When using joins, Rails tries to reference the primary key of the table, and this lack of a primary key can cause SQL syntax errors when trying to delete records.
you can first select the IDs of the records and then perform the delete operation:
[edited]
comment_ids = Comment.where(book_id: book_id).pluck(:id)

CommentsUser.where(comment_id: comment_ids, user_id: users_ids).delete_all


Alternatively, you can use a has_many :through association instead of has_and_belongs_to_many, it allows the join table to have a primary key.

yeah understood. then you have to preload all the ids of the comments then you can delete.

You can also combine it into a single db call: CommentsUser.where(comment_id: Comment.where(book_id: book_id).select(:id), user_id: users_ids).delete_all

There is very little of what you're doing here that makes sense.
Is the assocation between comments and users really many to many? That's pretty attypical.
What you actually want is most likely a one to many assocation between users and comments (a comment belongs to the user that wrote it):
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commenting_users, through: :comments, source: :user
end

# rails g model comment body:string book:belongs_to user:belongs_to
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commented_books, through: :comments, source: :book
end

In this case there is no need for a separate join table as the comments table is the the join table.
In a has_and_belongs_to_many assocation the association does not use a intermediate model. It's just a wrapper around a simple join table with the two foreign keys. It's only suitible when the join is just plumbing and you don't need any logic or additional columns to describe the relations between the two entities or need to create/delete the join table rows directly.
How often that scenario actually occurs is debatable.
If you want a join model use a has_many through: assocation and name the model CommentUser and table comment_users. You also need to ensure that the table has a primary key column or your model won't work very well. You can either just roll back and do it again the right way or rename the table in a migration and add the primary key if you have pushed this dud into production.
